# Break up long words in a UTF-8 text, with PHP

Tags: php

Horrible title, I know.

I want to have some kind of wordwrap, but obviously can not use wordwrap() as it messes up UTF-8.. not to mention markup.

My issue is that I want to get rid of stuff like this "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" .. but then longer of course. Some jokesters find it funny to put that stuff on my site.

So when I have a string like this "Hello how areeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee you doing?" I want to break up the 'areeee'-thing with the zero width space (​) character.

Strings aren't always the same letter, and strings are always inside larger strings.. so str_len, substr, wordwrap all don't really fit the description.

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Said that this is **not** a PHP solution, if your problem is the view of your script, why don't you use the simple CSS3 rule called [word-wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110215/#word-wrap)?

Let your container is a `div` with `id="example"`, you can write:

```
#example
{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work well for Chrome. But the real question; how does IE hold up? Edit: Oh.. can answer that myself. IE9 is doing okay. 1 follow up question then: is it a good idea to just put this on the body-element?

Comment: @GerbenJacobs I think you should me always more specific when you can so if you know where you need to wrap, be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in 3 steps

1. do a split on the string and whitespace
2. do a str_len/trim on each word in the string
3. concat the string back together

The downside to this would be that words longer than 10 chars would be broken as well.  So I would suggest adding some stuff in here to see if it is the same letter in a row over and over.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$string = "Hello how areeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee you doing?";
$strArr = explode(" ",$string);
foreach($strArr as $word) {
if(strlen($word) > 10) {
    $word = substr($word,0,10);
}

$wordArr[] = $word;
}

$newString = implode(" ",$wordArr);
print $newString;  // Prints "Hello how areeeeeeee you doing?"
```